# How to use the freshest code on docker-compose avoiding downtime in AWS CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, aws-code-deploy

I have a `Next.js` app deployed with `docker-compose` on AWS CodeDeploy. I setup a staging environment so every time a developer pushed a new commit to the `staging` branch, it will trigger the creation of a new deployment on CodeDeploy.

The application's `appspec.yml` has one script to start the application with `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`.

I thought that using the flag `--no-cache` while invoking the build would be enough to start the container from the freshest version of the code, however, we are seeing that the new deployments are successful but the changes are not reflected on the application.

How can I make sure that every deployment creates a new container from the freshest code avoiding any downtime?

```yaml
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: .
    destination: /home/ec2-user/app/
hooks:
  ApplicationStart:
   - location: scripts/run.sh
     timeout: 300
     runas: root
```

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/app
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

It should actually run a fresh container. However, you can try to remove unused data from your Docker system and also remove all volumes before you build a new image.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ec2-user/app &&
docker volume prune -f &&
docker system prune -f
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Another option is to check the processes `docker ps` to verify if a new container has been spun up.

Also, you can SSH into the running container and verify if your new changes are in the container (It's a long process but it is useful)

```
docker exec -it <container-name> sh
```